# Match/group HTML elements by their data attributes values

Tags: javascript

In the HTML I have multiple elements that are grouped by data attributes, but these attributes don't necessarily have the same parent:

Example:

```
<span data-toggle-trigger="1">Resources</span>
<p>......<p>
<span data-toggle-trigger="2">Alpha</span>
<div data-toggle-container="1"></div>
<p>......<p>
<span data-toggle-trigger="3">Beta</span>
<div data-toggle-container="2"></div>
<div data-toggle-container="3"></div>
```

The used attributes are:

```
data-toggle-trigger` and `data-toggle-container
```

The behavior I need:

When someone click on data-toggle-trigger something happens on data-toggle-container (like show/hide).

To get them:

```
   triggers = document.querySelectorAll(['data-toggle-trigger']);
    container = document.querySelectorAll(['data-toggle-container']);
```

It looks like I have two options:

1. To get all of them and try to group them
2. To get only triggers and than search after that for containers

I'm inclining for 1), but I don't know what the best option is to group.

My naive approach is to think/use `2 for nested loops` and loop and compare value, but I don't know if is the best option. So I'm looking for some opinion regarding a good approach.

Important - I'm using pure JavaScript, no ECMAScript 6 syntax sugar (because of other stuff).

Comment: Why do you need to get all of them? You can make eventListener on all `data-toggle-trigger` and find specific one when someone click's on it.

Comment: if I get all of them, I can store them as a model, otherwise every time some elements toggle, I need to interrogate the DOM

Comment: @user3541631 Browsers are smart enough to cache `querySelector`[`All`]`()` calls, benchmark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is opinion-based, but I think the most efficient solution is to have only one event listener, possibly on `<body>`, and if the target has `.dataset.toggleTrigger`, then show/hide all matching elements, i.e., `querySelectorAll('[data-toggle-container="' + x + '"]')` in a loop.

Comment: unfortunately I need to support IE, which doesn't work or well with dataset, do you know a shim for IE ?

Comment: @user3541631 `.hasAttribute('data-toggle-trigger')`

Answer (score 0):

I would add classes to manage your triggers and containers. Here is example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fswht0zu/1/).
In this snippet I add text every time you click on a trigger.

```
function myFunction(numberOfTriggerClicked) {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle-container='"+numberOfTriggerClicked+"']")[0];
    element.innerText += " NEW TEXT";
}
```